# Array reshape issue while time series prediction with ConvLSTM in Python

Tags: python, numpy, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

I am using ConvLSTM for time series prediction (univariate series) with time step=4. The dataframe has two columns viz. timestamp and amount. The amount column contains continuous values and then we divide the dataframe into train and test.The training data has some 12777 observations and the test has 3181 observations. Here's the code:

```
from numpy import array
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import ConvLSTM2D

# data prep
def split_sequence(sequence, n_steps):
    X, y = list(), list()
    for i in range(len(sequence)):
        end_ix = i + n_steps
        if end_ix > len(sequence)-1:
            break
        seq_x, seq_y = sequence[i:end_ix], sequence[end_ix]
        X.append(seq_x)
        y.append(seq_y)
    return array(X), array(y)

raw_seq = train['amount'].values
n_steps = 4
# split into samples
X, y = split_sequence(raw_seq, n_steps)
# reshape from [samples, timesteps] into [samples, timesteps, rows, columns, features]
n_features = 1
n_seq = 2
n_steps = 2
X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], n_seq, 1, n_steps, n_features))
# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(1,2), activation='relu', input_shape=(n_seq, 1, n_steps, n_features)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
# fit model
model.fit(X, y, epochs=500, verbose=0)

#prediction
raw_seq2 = test['amount'].values 
X_input, y_input = split_sequence(raw_seq2, n_steps)
X_input = X_input.reshape((X_input.shape[0], n_seq, 1, n_steps, n_features))
yhat = model.predict(X_input, verbose=0)

mean_absolute_error(y_input, yhat)
```

But when executing the following:

```
X_input = X_input.reshape((X_input.shape[0], n_seq,1, n_steps, n_features))
```

I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 6358 into shape (3179,2,2,1)
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an issue of pure math: You're trying to fit the dimension of size `6358` into multiple dimensions of sizes `3179 * 2 * 2 * 1 = 12716`. Try setting `n_seq = 1` or `n_steps = 1`, this way the data will have the same size when reshaping.